# How to avoid duplication in regex

Tags: regex

Say I have the following regex: `a+ a+`

The `a+` part needs to be matched twice but unfortunately it is duplicated, meaning that for every change to the `a+`, I actually need to make the change 2 times.

How can I rewrite such regex without that duplication so that it is easier to read and maintain?

PS: The `a+` is actually a bit more complex.

Comment: I mean the duplication in the regex itself. The regex `a+ a+` is already doing what it is supposed to, it's more a readability/maintainability issue.

Comment: Yeah we really need more info than this. Add a list of various strings that should/shouldn't be matched and don't hide the important part from us. If it's simply matching the same thing twice you could do a{2}

Comment: When you mean that try "(a+)\1"

Comment: What are you trying to match against?

Comment: I agree with @Laoujin, But if you don't want to write a+ again You can use Use /(a+) \1/

Comment: @ShyamBabuKushwaha: `(a+) \1` is different from `a+ a+`. The former doesn't match `a aa`, but the latter does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with *subroutines*:

```
(a+) (?1)
```

[Reference 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html), [Reference 2](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines)

> **Perl 5.10, PCRE 4.0, and Ruby 1.9 support regular expression subroutine calls.** These are very similar to regular expression recursion. Instead of matching the entire regular expression again, a subroutine call only matches the regular expression inside a capturing group. You can make a subroutine call to any capturing group from anywhere in the regex. If you place a call inside the group that it calls, you'll have a recursive capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep parts of your regexp in string variables of the language you are using and compose the complete regexp out of them like this:

```
var complexPart = 'a+';    
var completeRegexp = new RegExp(complexPart + ' ' + complexPart);
```

If you are just need a regexp to be used in some app you don't control, then subroutines are a way to go: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines if the engine the app uses supports them

```
(a+) (?1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
(?:a+(?: |$)){2}
```

However, this will also match strings with a trailing space, so you'll probably want to add a lookbehind to prevent that:

```
(?:a+(?: |$)){2}(?<! )
```

Note that you've avoided duplicating the `a+` pattern, but in exchange you have duplicated the separating space .

Also note that this won't work if your pattern can end with a space, e.g. `[a ]+ [a ]+`.

Comment: This would work only if you are matching whole line (or at least your match is at the end of line or endint with space). It won't match anything in string "Abc aaa aaa. tralala"

Answer (score -1):

I dont know exactly what you want, but you can match sequence N times like this:

```
(a+){N}
```

or less or equal to N times, between M and N times, or more than N times:

```
(a+){,N}
(a+){N,M}
(a+){N,}
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the space in between.

Comment: if there is only 1 space in the middle and no space at the end, then I don't know any way without duplicating regex. You can hack it like in Rawing example (but only if you are matching whole line) or like (a+ ?){N}